# Correct parameter to pass a bound event to treeview.identify/identify_region in Tkinter?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I have a couple of `treeviews` tkinter widgets. For style purposes i need to prevent a manual resizing of the `treeview` columns *width* without totally disableing column resize.

Using a possible solution provided here: [How to disable manual resizing of Tkinter's Treeview column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358408/how-to-disable-manual-resizing-of-tkinters-treeview-column) i am catching single click events on `separators` between the columns and stop the event there. For this purpose every `treeview` binds a handling function.

Example:

```
self.tree.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: handle_treeview_single_click(self.tree, event))

def handle_treeview_single_click(tree, event):
    if tree.identify_region(event.x, event.y) == 'separator':
        return 'break'
```

Running the code produce the following error:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\lib-tk\ttk.py", line 1277, in identify
    return self.tk.call(self._w, "identify", component, x, y)
TclError: bad component "region": must be row or column
```

this doesn't change regardless the object i click on (Header, cell or separator). For example the relating parameter look like this:

```
tree = Treeview: .42424440.47830640.47831440.47831800.47831840
x = 464 
y = 14
```

Not sure what im missing here, even more since im fairly new to python.

Comment: I fully understand the reason behind the downvote. From the perspectiv of an experienced developer it may look like a dumb question. Using pycharm and debugging it as an inexperiencend one it was still hard to point out the problem. I tried a lot before posting here. 

Referring to: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/  

Maybe you can think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a comment in the ttk source code that explains why this might not be working:

```
def identify_region(self, x, y):
    """
    ...
    * Availability: Tk 8.6"""
    return self.identify("region", x, y)
```

Since you're using python 2.7, you probably aren't using tk 8.6. You can verify this by printing out the value of `Tkinter.TkVersion`

Comment: I verified the version and you are absolutly right. It's 8.5. Thanks a lot.